# How do I ng-src bind an image?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to use data-ng-src to display a pictures in my angular application.  I get a value from my database field called "pic". For example let say the return value of the field **"pic"** is **125**(this is an integer value).  I have a image file on my server called **125.jpg** at file location

```
\\someserv\zpicturesFiles\zpicturesResources\Database\VFP\PhotoID\itc\portrait\
```

I need to render this in my html, but I don't know how to attach the file location with the value in the binding {{e.pic}}.  I need {{e.pic}} to pickup

```
\\someserv\zpicturesFiles\zpicturesResources\Database\VFP\PhotoID\itc\portrait\125.jpg
```

but currently {{e.pic}} has an integer value of 125 (because that what it returned from sql server db).  How can I make {{e.pic}} see the value of \someserv\zpicturesFiles\zpicturesResources\Database\VFP\PhotoID\itc\portrait\125.jpg.  This is in an ng-repeat.  Here is my code so far implementing the suggestion below.

```
<section class="mainbar" data-ng-controller="employees as vm">
....
    <div class="padd" data-ng-repeat="e in vm.employees">
        <div class="user">
             <img data-ng-src="{{'\\someserv\zpicturesFiles\zpicturesResources\Database\VFP\PhotoID\itc\portrait\' + e.pic + '.jpg' }}">  
                  class="img-polaroid user-pic"/>
```

I am getting an error as follows:

> Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unterminated quote at columns
>   97-99 [' ] in expression
>   ['\someserv\zpicturesFiles\zpicturesResources\Database\VFP\PhotoID\itc\portrait\'
>   + e.pic + '.jpg' ]. http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.12/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unterminated%20quote&p1=s%2097-99%20%5B'%20%5D&p2='%5C%5Csomeserv%5CzpictureFiles%5CzpicturesResources%5CDatabase%5CVFP%5CPhotoID%5Citc%5Cportrait%5C'%20%2B%20e.pic%20%2B%20'.jpg'%20
>       at http:// localhost:56014/scripts/angular.js:78:12

what is it not liking?

thanks
Nick

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/BM6TG/).  The reason I added the `e.pick && '\...'` is because ng-src will hide until the value is valid.  In the fiddle you will see `broken` will flash with a broken image, until `pathExt` is set.

Use:

```
<img data-ng-src="{{e.pic && '\fileserver\pictures\' + e.pic + '.jpg' }}"
```

---

Alternatively create something on your scope to make it cleaner:

```
$scope.getImage = function(e){
    return e && e.pic && ('\fileserver\pictures\' + e.pic + '.jpg');
}
```

HTML:

```
<img data-ng-src="getImage(e)" >
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I got following error:  [app]  [EP Error] [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unterminated quote at columns 106-107 ['] in expression [e.pic && '\\fileserver\pictures\' + e.pic + '.jpg'].  I think it's because e.pic is a numerical value.  Is it possible to change that to text value in the UI?

Comment: @Nick what method did you use?   (the function or html).  I used both in the fiddle w/o issue.